# "Any individual" vs "the particular"

Tags: word-choice, definite-articles

I want to say that certain works in a plant need to be adapted according to the specific requirements of ***each individual*** operating unit within the plant, and I'm not sure whether both *any individual* and *the particular* could be used to say that each unit needs to be considered separately when planning the work:

> Electrical installations need to be adapted to **any individual/the particular** operating unit in question.

For some reason *any individual* sounds better to me than *any particular* in this context, but I'm not sure about that either. I am also not sure if or to what degree *in question* is redundant in this sentence, i.e. if there's a sense of definiteness lost when it is left out from the sentence.

Comment: Is there a reason to avoid "to each individual operating unit" or "to each particular operating unit"?  Is there a question in evidence that would establish which units require adaptation:?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions Gary, and no, there is no reason I'd need to avoid those expressions, but this question is typical of the problem I have with definitiness/indefinitiness distinction in English, especially with the use of articles for that purpose. I'm wondering if "the" in combination with "in question" indicates clearly enough that I'm referring to one of the units which I individualized to give an example which applies to all units.

Comment: If you're referring to one specific unit, use "*the* particular/individual unit"; if you're referring to multiple units, use "*each* particular/individual unit" as you have done.